# Returning data from WebMethod to ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webforms

I need to return DataTable to Ajax from c#(WebMethod).
I'm sending 'Value" to WebMethod. Value is received and used as a parameter for a procedure in the code below(getObj.getValuesTableAdapter(Value);).

Then procedure returns datatable(dtObj) and ajax should receive it back in the "success" part. 
I need help with these code. I tried everything but failed.

I can't return DataTable directly from  [WebMethod] like this. I need to convert  DataTable to JSON before sending to client somehow.

This is my c# code:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static DataTable GetObject(int Value)
{
    LogicTableAdapters.getValuesTableAdapter getObj = new LogicTableAdapters.getValuesTableAdapter();

    DataTable getObj = getObj.getValuesTableAdapter(Value);
    DataTable dtObj = new DataTable();
    dtObj.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4]{ 
        new DataColumn("ObjectID", typeof(string)), 
        new DataColumn("ObjectName", typeof(string)), 
        new DataColumn("ObjectValue", typeof(string)), 
        new DataColumn("ParentID", typeof(int)),
    });

    foreach (DataRow dr in getObj.Rows)
    {
        dtCh.Rows.Add(dr["ObjectID"].ToString(), dr["ObjectName"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["ObjectValue"].ToString(), dr["ParentID"].ToString());
    }
    return dtObj;
}
```

This is my ajax:

```
$(document).on('click', ".Btn", function () {
    header = $(this).closest('tr').find('.ColumnID').text()
    console.log(Value);   

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyAdmin.aspx/GetObject",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'Value': Value }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function () {
           //code that should receive datatable to be displayed
        },

        error: function () {
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try following**

**create a class for sending data to frontend**

```
 public class DataForClientSide
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value{ get; set; }
    }
```

**Edit Your webmethod as follow**

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

    public static DataForClientSide[] GetObject(int Value)
    {
List<DataForClientSide> details = new List<DataForClientSide>();
        LogicTableAdapters.getValuesTableAdapter getObj = new LogicTableAdapters.getValuesTableAdapter();

        DataTable getObj = getObj.getValuesTableAdapter(Value);
        DataTable dtObj = new DataTable();
        dtObj.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4]{ new DataColumn("ObjectID", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("ObjectName", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("ObjectValue", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("ParentID", typeof(int)),       

                    });

        foreach (DataRow dr in getObj.Rows)
        {
                        DataForClientSide Info= new DataForClientSide();
                        Info.id = dr["ObjectID"].ToString();
                        Info.name = dr["ObjectName"].ToString();
                        Info.value = dr["ObjectValue"].ToString();
                        //multiple data as u want. . . . . 
                        details.Add(Info);

        }
        return details.ToArray();
    }
```

**Write following code in your ajax function to get values**

```
 success: function (data) {
               if(data.d.length>0)
               {
                 $.each(data,function(i,values){
                 //you can get all values as per each iteration as follow
                 //to get id
                 values.id;
                 //to get name
                 values.name;
                 //to get value
                 values.value;
                 });
               }

            }
```